# Cannot create bundled product, products are empty

Tags: magento-1, bundled-product

I have two test products:

[image]

When I try to create a bundled product out of them, I do not see any products in the list here:

[image]

Any idea why this might be? Are the two test products created incorrectly? Are they meant to be "related" products to this bundled product?

Comment: Press 'Reset Filter'

Comment: Maybe these products have custom options?

Comment: sorry I spoke too soon, it worked.